# Out Of Memory Exception : Add a range

Tags: c#, sql, out-of-memory

The code below returns an `OutOfMemoryException` when importing the database, I need to import 40000 different concepts, my computer can hold that many, however I think there is some limit into how many can be added at once.
What I want to do is make it so that it adds a 1000 at a time saves changes then repeats this process until it has gone through the entire database...
How would one go about this?

```
public static void writeOutConcepts(List<Gnome.Data.Concept> concepts, HttpResponseBase    Response)
{
    var ctx = new GnomeContext();
    Response.Write("Writing out concepts: \n");
    Response.Flush();
    try
    {
        ctx.Concepts.AddRange(concepts);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Response.Write(error.Message);
        Response.Write(error.StackTrace);
        Response.Flush();
        throw;
    }
    Response.Write("Writing of Concepts complete\n\n");
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Look into modulus operator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what impact will be using transaction but you could try this:

```
using (var transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
   int i = 0;
   foreach(var concept in concepts)
   {
      ctx.Concepts.Add(concept);
      i++;

      if (i >= 1000)
      {
         i = 0;
         ctx.SaveChanges();
      }
   }
   ctx.SaveChanges()

   transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: This appears to be working, there is no way, as of yet to tell... But, an error hasn't come up yet which indicates it has worked. Thank you.